# Java substring issue

Tags: java, string, substring

**EDIT: Thank you, PakkuDon**

**instead of using "==" I must use ".Equals()"!**

---

I'm trying to implement a chat-command system though I've encountered troubles in differentiating between standard chat and command chat..

Focusing on just one command for now, `` `highlight ``

the output whenever I type in `` `highlight `` is:

```
 highlight
`highlight
```

Here's my code:

```
    String cmd =  InMessage.message.substring(0, 10);
    System.out.println(cmd);
    System.out.println("`highlight");
    if( cmd == "`highlight" )
    {
       ... cancel chat packet and proces command
    }
```

and yet the if statement returns false.

What's going on here? Anything I've done is wrong?

Comment: Read [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: And, your sample output is mixing upper and lower case, so `equals` will also return false.

Comment: In case you are using Java 7 or above, you can use Strings in switch statements too.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems.  Firstly, that `substring` is going to throw an exception if the user types something that's less than 10 characters.  Secondly, you're using == where `equals` would work better.  But you don't need either of these things.  You could just use

```
if (InMessage.message.startsWith("`highlight")) {
    // whatever
}
```